# Use a Controller smarty variable in another template file

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop

Hey guys hope you all right:!!

I need your help; my problem is that I want to use a smarty variable of HistoryController in myaccount.tpl

Is it possible, for example to change something and so to that the variable be used also in myaccount

copy the part of code define the needed variable in MyaccountController is not an option because I need to do a special treatment that only work locally in HistoryController/

Comment: Give us some code so that we know about what you speak please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use override of MyAccountController and place it in override > controllers > front?

Like this

```
<?php

class MyAccountController extends MyAccountControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $total_orders = 0;

        if ($orders = Order::getCustomerOrders($this->context->customer->id))
            $total_orders = count($orders);

            $this->context->smarty->assign('total_orders', $total_orders);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to delete cache/class_index.php